# Currency Converter API not working in Android

Tags: java, android, currency

I am encountering a problem where my Yahoo Finance API is not working in my code.  I am creating a realtime currency converter.  I have checked Google but nothing seems to answer my question.  When I press the "Calculate" button in my app, nothing happens.  Here is the code I put in.

```
        public interface CurrencyConverter {
    public double convert(String currencyFrom, String currencyTo) throws Exception;
}

public class YahooCurrencyConverter implements CurrencyConverter{
     public double convert(String currencyFrom, String currencyTo) throws IOException {
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("http://quote.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=" + currencyFrom + currencyTo + "=X&f=l1&e=.csv");
            ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
            String responseBody = httpclient.execute(httpGet, responseHandler);
            httpclient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
            return Double.parseDouble(responseBody);
}


}
     public void convertDollarstoEuros(){
    double current;
    double val = Double.parseDouble(edittextdollars.getText().toString());
    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat(".##");
     YahooCurrencyConverter ycc = new YahooCurrencyConverter();

        try {
            current = ycc.convert("USD", "EUR");
            edittexteuros.setText(df.format(val*current)); 
            }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

I have the internet permission in my manifest file and I have installed the Google API in my Android SDK.  Something seems to be wrong with my code, but I can't identify it.  This is what comes up when I remove the try/catch method:
[image: http://oi40.tinypic.com/2sah6d5.jpg]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please copy and paste the error message here.

Comment: Also copy and paste the exception from your log cat when you have the try/catch statement.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely "nothing happens" because you are catching all exceptions. I suggest that you remove the `try...catch` block, or at the very least catch the *specific* exceptions that you need to handle, and let the Java exception system do the rest of the work for you. I strongly suggest that you learn more about Java's exception handling system. [The Oracle tutorial on Exceptions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/) is a great place to start. The first two lessons will give you the basics that you need to know for 99% of what you encounter in Android programming.

In addition, you should check the logcat to see if any exceptions *are* thrown.

**Edit: A little bit about Exceptions**

Notice that some of the text is blue in the popup message. This means that you can click on it and Eclipse will generate some code for you. I suggest that you click on "Surround with try/catch" and note how the generated code differs from what you have posted here. This is a great tool to use when you understand how and when to use try/catch statements.

In this particular case, I think that "Add throws declaration" is a better option. Click on it and see what happens. You most likely will get similar errors elsewhere in your code. You should keep adding throws declarations to each method that doesn't know how to deal with the exception. You should only add a try/catch statement to a method that knows what to do when an error occurs. This is usually in the UI code such as a Listener method.

Comment: Android isn't allowing me to remove the try/catch method.

Comment: @user2507301 What do you mean?

Comment: When I remove the try/catch method, an error shows up with the option saying to put in the try/catch method.

Comment: @user2507301 Please edit your question with the *exact* error message so that we can suggest alternative solutions.

Comment: @user2507301 Yes, that too

Comment: @user2507301 Please edit your original question by pasting the error message there.